Powershell throwing 'The filename or extension is too long' error, when providing filepaths to a native command
This is a issue I have come across many times, especially when using native commands that are built on Python.
For example today, I have a series of images (about 700) and I would like to take these images and pass them to a native command called img2pdf, in order to output a single PDF document.
A snippet of the image paths are:
C:\Users\ralf\Documents\raw scans\volume 39\chapter 1\Page_1.png
C:\Users\ralf\Documents\raw scans\volume 39\chapter 1\Page_2.png
C:\Users\ralf\Documents\raw scans\volume 39\chapter 1\Page_3.png
C:\Users\ralf\Documents\raw scans\volume 39\chapter 1\Page_4.png
C:\Users\ralf\Documents\raw scans\volume 39\chapter 1\Page_5.png
C:\Users\ralf\Documents\raw scans\volume 39\chapter 1\Page_6.png
C:\Users\ralf\Documents\raw scans\volume 39\chapter 1\Page_7.png
...
C:\Users\ralf\Documents\raw scans\volume 39\chapter 1\Page_687.png

and the command:
$images = get-childitem -path 'C:\Users\ralf\Documents\raw scans\volume 39\chapter 1' | sort creation time
Img2PDF $images -o "chapter1.pdf"

but the above fails with:
ResourceUnavailable: Program 'img2pdf.exe' failed to run: An error occurred trying to start process 'C:\Users\ralf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\img2pdf.exe' with working directory 'C:\Users\ralf\Documents\raw scans\volume 39\chapter 1'. The filename or extension is too long.At line:1 char:1

If I just pass the paths for the first 5 image, the command works and the document is generated. Sometimes, I even get it to work by

Placing the images at c:\temp\Page_1.png, c:\temp\Page_2.png etc
Then invoking image2pdf and passing the new paths
Finally moving them back to their original location
But this is not ideal and sometimes I mess up really badly and have to clean it up.

Many times I tried to solve this problem, once I followed this guide and enabled LongPathsEnabled in my registry but after restarting, this did not have any effect. its even enabled right now.
This issue is keeps cropping up in the most critical of times and I would really like to deal with it for once, thanks for any help.

I guess you need to send it the full path and filenames, not the fileinfo objects. Try Img2PDF $images.FullName. also, there is no property creation time.. Did you mean LastWriteTime perhaps? P.S. better also append switch -File to the Get-ChildItem command to rule out Directories it may also find

Pardon me, I meant to use the CreationTime property, which I believe corresponds to 'Date Created' column in explorer. Also PowerShell will correctly pass the FullName property to the native command. As for -file, I am certain of there only being files in the directory, good call for those who may come to find this page usefull later on though.

try prepending \\?\ to the paths before passing to img2pdf

I think I have a simple solution for you to try. Map a drive to your folder, process the files based on the mapped drive, remove the mapping.
$tmpDrive = New-PSDrive -Name G -PSProvider FileSystem -Root 'C:\Users\ralf\Documents\raw scans\volume 39\chapter 1' -Persist
$images = get-childitem -path G:\ | sort LastWriteTime
Img2PDF $images -o "chapter1.pdf"
$tmpDrive | Remove-PSDrive

*Thanks for phuclv for the suggestion to add -Persist.

I tried this, it too ends up throwing the same error that I mentioned in the OP. Its a very clever solution but it seems that attempting to get the items on the "PsDrive" just ends up returning a path that resolves to the actual "physical" path. Doing get-childitem g:\ |% fullname returns paths starting with C:\Users\ralf\... rather than g:\. I wish this worked, I could thinks of hundreds of uses for it lol.

you may need -Persist to make it more similar to subst in cmd or a mapped drive in Explorer: New-PSDrive -Name G -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root 'C:\Users\ralf\Documents\raw scans\volume 39\chapter 1' -Persist. But it's even better if you have a separate partition and mount it to an NTFS folder, or create a symlink to another folder

@phuclv with the -persist option, I was able to get it done. I marked it as the answer, though in it the answer -persist  is missing. Perhaps TheMadTechnician can edit his answer to include -persist. Either way thank you both, I will keep the NTFS folder/symlink suggestion in mind too!
